# Non existent RAID causing crash

Tags: raid

I have nonexistent RAID according to `mdadm md10`.

It periodically totally crashes my OS with an error:

> timed out ... accessing md10.

Is there another way to delete this - it REALLY does not exist in `mdadm` nor elsewhere like `gparted` doesn't see it in my system.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid5 sde18[3] sdb4[4] sdb17[1]
      409335808 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/2 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

NO md10

Here is part of journal, just confirming that "md10" is configured somewhere... question remains - WHERE?

```
:0\x2dpart1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.device/start timed out.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: mnt-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.mount: Job mnt-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0\x2dusb\x2d0:1.3:1.0\x2dscsi\x2d0:0:0:0\x2dpart5.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: dev-md10.device: Job dev-md10.device/start timed out.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/md10.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/md10.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: mnt-md10.mount: Job mnt-md10.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 01 19:12:46 q5-desktop systemd[1]: dev-md10.device: Job dev-md10.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

My best guess is - an incomplete RAID 5 - perhaps only ONE disk - is somehow trying  to recover the md10... the RAID "device" has to be mounted and that is failing...

Can I "list all devices mounte"?

Here is the requested `cat /etc/fstab`

I did run the last sugesstion to "remove " the mount but cannot access that to copy here. I'll try when done editing here.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sde31 during installation
UUID=8a11a155-c003-4bf8-9eb6-9505e4a88085 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sde1 during installation
UUID=2792-8CD9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md10 /mnt/md10 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_9718791054593227694-0:0-part1 /mnt/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_9718791054593227694-0:0-part1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=USB_125_J 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_0769581094151700277-0:0 /mnt/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_0769581094151700277-0:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=USB_125_2 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_9718791054593227694-0:0-part2 /mnt/usb-VendorCo_ProductCode_9718791054593227694-0:0-part2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=USB_124_PART_2 0 0
/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5 /mnt/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=MDI_RAID_5 /mnt/MDI_RAID_5 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/md127 /mnt/md127 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have systemd unit related to  /dev/md10. It wants mount /dev/md10 to /mnt/md10.

Disable it

```
 systemctl disable mnt-md10.mount
```

Also you have in fstab

```
 /dev/md10 /mnt/md10 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment out this line.

Comment: You may reboot to check it works

Comment: Rebooted several  times and so far no "md10"  crash. I'll clean up the fstab - there is some more garbage there...